# C# Array Class[]

Tags: c#

i have 3 class, programclass,bioskop class, kursi class

> this class program:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Bioskop bioskop = new Bioskop("test", "test");
        bioskop.tampilDenah();
    }
}
```

> this class Kursi:

```
class Kursi
{
    public int noKursi { set; get; }
    public bool tersedia { set; get; }
}
```

> this class Bioskop:

```
class Bioskop
{
    Kursi[] arrKursi { set; get; }
    public string noBioskop { set; get; }
    public string judulFilm { set; get; }

    public Bioskop (string noBioskop,string judulFilm)
    {
        this.noBioskop = noBioskop
        this.judulFilm = judulFilm
        arrKursi = new Kursi[41]
    };


    public void tampilDenah()
    {
        for (int i = 0;i<41;i++)
        {
            arrKursi[i].noKursi = i;
            Console.Write(arrKursi[i].noKursi);
        }
    }
}
```

why i cant print arrKursi[i].noKursi?
error in arrKursi[i].noKursi = i.
some one please help me

Comment: What error fo you get

Comment: `arrKursi = new Kursi[41]` will create an array of `null`. You need to give each element a *value*. `arrKursi[i] = new Kursi();`

Comment: Please read specifically the 'Array' section of the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void tampilDenah()
{
    for (int i = 0;i<41;i++)
    {
        arrKursi[i] = new Kursi();
        arrKursi[i].noKursi = i;
        Console.Write(arrKursi[i].noKursi);
    }
}
```

Comment: still error (null) bro, error at arrKursi[i] = new Kursi();

Comment: Did you changed the default constructor?

Comment: i just change method tampilDenah() like ur answer

Comment: @WillyLaw Your Kursi has custom default constructor? Does your class is like what you posted?